# Redux: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to combine actions inside mapDispatchToProps. Trying to fetch data and after launch modal dialog. But I keep getting *Cannot read property 'then' of undefined* error.

Could somebody explain me, what am I doing wrong?

mapDispatchToProps:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onClick: id => {
    // console.log(fetchThing(id)) returns undefined
    dispatch(fetchThing(id)).then(() => {
      dispatch(showModal())
    })
  }
})
```

Redux action:

```
export const fetchThing = () => {
  const request = axios.get(URL_API)

  return dispatch => {
    request.then(response => {
      dispatch({ type: ACTION_FETCH, payload: response.data })
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have so many dispatches within dispatches and why are you dispatching the result of random functions? Normally reducers should be pure functions with no asynchronous calls so I'm not surprised you get certain things undefined. Maybe post the complete files to see exactly what the dispatches are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `redux-thunk`? With that you can write your action like that:

```
export const fetchThing = dispatch => axios.get(URL_API)
  .then(response => dispatch({ type: ACTION_FETCH, payload: response.data }))
```

[Redux thunk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk) middleware will do all the stuff for you and you do not need to do that each time you need async actions within the `mapDispatchToProps`.

Answer (score 0):

`mapDispatchToProps` should not have side effects. This should only do as the name suggests and hook up the actions to redux. This should be:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  fetchThing: yourAction.fetchThing,
  showModal: yourAction.showModal,
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(YourComponent);
```

Then in your (probably) button:

```
<button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick} />

// this can be an asynchronous function, or you can just handle it in the action.
handleClick = async id => {
  await this.props.fetchThing(id);
  this.props.showModal();
};
```

Comment: Can use what ever you like, e.g. `.then`, etc.